# Azure Key Vault best practices

Tags: azure, security, azure-keyvault

We are developing an Azure multi-tenant web service portal that calls external API services. Each called web service may have oAuth parameters such as end point, client Id, secret, etc. Currently, we 2 flavors of working code:

1. uses SQL to store these parameters; and
2. uses a json config file to maintain runtime parameters. I would like to offer a Azure Key Vault solution, but it seems unwise to have both a Client ID and Client Secret in the same Key Vault.

Additionally, we have many subscribers in our multi-tenant model, and each may have a specific config (for example: Solr collection name, SQL Db connection string; etc.) and I am wondering about comingling these runtime parameter verses allowing the customer to have their own Vault which of course requires that the customer share access with us as a SaaS vendor. We want to offer best practices security to our subscribers, many of which are Fintechs. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"but it seems unwise to have both a Client ID and Client Secret in the same Key Vault"

Why would you store these in the same database or JSON - far less secure.

Have you looked at [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/#features), this is by far the best way to amalgamate services.

If you are too far down the road, use KeyVault. Use MSI (Managed Service Identity) to connect from your app service / function app, limit access Keys, Secrets, Get, List, Read, Write. Limit access via the firewall. Make sure all diagnostics are logged.

If you need a per-client model and not a multi-tenant, then deploy separate instances of the portal or API management for each. Per-client is more expensive and more tricky to maintain, but far more secure because you can enforce physical partitional on a number of fronts.